# Regex Syntax Misuse

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am running this query:

```
Select column_name
from table
where column_name ~ '%[A-Za-z]%'
group by column_name
```

but I am not getting any results. What am I doing wrong?

Goal: This is a column that includes phone numbers. I am trying to find any values that contain string characters.

I don't understand why ilike does not support regex
This is what I found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)

> The operator ~~ is equivalent to LIKE, and ~~* corresponds to ILIKE. There are also !~~ and !~~* operators that represent NOT LIKE and NOT ILIKE, respectively. All of these operators are PostgreSQL-specific.

Doesn't this mean I can use ilike by using ~~*?

Edit: What I have learned so far

1. Don't use like, use tilda.
2. `Where column_name ~ '%[A]%'`
3. `Where column_name ~ $$[A]$$` does work.

Theory: It has something to with the dollar signs or the apostrophe.
Result: It was the `%` signs.

Comment: `ILIKE` doesn't support regex - it only supports the wildcards that `LIKE` supports. If you want regex use the `~`  operator. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post to reflect what I am doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/), the correct syntax for the `WHERE` clause is:

```
WHERE mycolumn ~ $$[A-Z]$$
```

Comment: It worked!!!! I typed the query incorrectly from what you gave me, my mistake. I left the % signs in.

Comment: If lower case characters are an issue, use `~ '[A-Za-z]'` to find anything that contains non-digits, use `~ '[^0-9]'`